trying to install using npm install or npx creat bugges my terminal
When I try to create a new Next.js app or install xata I receive bugs in my terminal.
❯ npm cache clean --force
npm warn using --force Recommended protections disabled.
❯ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
❯ npm i
⠼^C
❯ npm install -g npm@latest
⠧^C
❯ npm -v
10.8.2
❯ node -v
v22.5.0
❯ sudo npm install
Password:
⠦^C
❯ npm run dev

my-next-app@0.1.0 dev
next dev

sh: next: command not found
 ~/Desktop/testauth/my-next-app ·············································
❯
package.json:
{
"name": "my-next-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",
"next": "14.2.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"typescript": "^5",
"@types/node": "^20",
"@types/react": "^18",
"@types/react-dom": "^18",
"postcss": "^8",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
"eslint": "^8",
"eslint-config-next": "14.2.5"
}
}
I don't have the package-lock.json and node_modules directory

I think You are making a minor mistake before running the next-app. Follow the steps I suggest you.
First clear the Cache of the file by running the command.
npm cache clean --force

Then Delete the node-modules folder through command and if the command does not work which possibly happen a lot then delete the node-modules from the root file.
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json

After then close all the file reopen it again and run the following command.
npm install

Then First check did this command also install the .next folder to your folder if not then Run this command.
npm install -g npm@latest

After that also run this
npm install next

Then Go into your working dir and run the
npm run dev

I hope this will help you resolve your issue. If it does or does not do Inform me so I figure out more for your problem.
